# CountIf with relative reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column, G, with several dates in it, and another column, K, with several percentage values between 0 and 100%.

I also have an UDF, IsoWeekNumber, which returns the weeknumber for any given date.

What I want to do is have weeks 1 to 53 in N3:N55, and then have a formula in the column next to it counting how many of the entries for a given week aren't 100%. I've come up with this formula, but it seems that it gets the weeknumber for cell G3 only when doing the comparison.

```
=COUNTIFS($G$3:$G$649;IsoWeekNumber(G3)&"="&$N$3;$K$3:$K$649;"<>"&1)
```

So, is there any way to make the function inside the countif apply to each of the cells I am comparing? Is there a better alternative approach?

**Addendum:** UDF code from OP's comments -

```
Public Function IsoWeekNumber(InDate As Date) As Long
  IsoWeekNumber = DatePart("ww", InDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
End Function
```

Comment: As you have not provided the code for the custom  *User Defined Function* I cannot test this but you might try `=SUMPRODUCT(--(IsoWeekNumber($G$3:$G$649)=$N$3); --($K$3:$K$649<>1))`. Whether works or not will depend on the coding for `IsoWeekNumber` but the method works for native worksheet functions that typically take a single cell as an input, e.g. `MONTH` and `YEAR`.

Comment: Here's the code for the UFD (as well as the address it can be found at) `IsoWeekNumber(InDate As Date) As Long IsoWeekNumber = DatePart("ww", InDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) End Function` (cpearson.com/excel/WeekNumbers.aspx) Function) I'll give both of your suggestions a go, and come back with which best satisfy my needs. @Jeeped @pnuts

Comment: Neither your UDF or Excel 2010's expanded [WEEKNUM function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-036e4d0c-3d68-44b5-bd38-59b881b36047) (e.g. `=WEEKNUM(G3, 21)` will work on arrays. My best suggestion would be a *helper column* of the weeknums where the result values would be dealt with directly.

Comment: I noticed :) I couldn't quite manage to get a pivot table to do what I wanted either, so like you I can't really see any other option than introducing a helper column with the weeknumbers. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT((ISOWEEKNUM($G$3:$G$649)=N3)*($K$3:$K$649<>1))`

Comment: With the Excel function ISOWEEKNUM the above worked but with your UDF it didn't. Maybe you could use the non-VB method of obtaining the Iso week number and nest that in a sumproduct formula `sumproduct((TRUNC(($G$3:$G$649-WEEKDAY($G$3:$G$649,2)+11-("1/"&YEAR($G$3:$G$649+4-WEEKDAY($G$3:$G$649,2))))/7)=N3)*($K$3:$K$649<>1))`